# Using OAuth to secure services that use SSO

Tags: api, authentication, oauth, authorization, single-sign-on

This is a conceptual challenge that I'm trying to wrap my mind around. Let's say I have an SSO (single sign on) service and two separate web services that use it. Let's say that the SSO login happens via OAuth, just like Login with Facebook. (Correct me if I'm wrong that they're not just requesting an OAuth access token for the site in question.)

The question is then, how should the two web services expose their own APIs to third parties? Given that we've drunken the OAuth kool aid, it seems logical that the third parties should be considered OAuth consumers and they should request that the user approves an access token for them. Accepting that the question is, should the the web services handle all this OAuth stuff themselves, having the third parties register as OAuth consumers with them and only using the SSO to login the user? Or, should the web services hand all responsibility off to the SSO service? For signed requests, the web service would check the validity of the access token via the SSO's API and then process it as normal.

I see pluses and minuses to both approaches. On one hand, the first option places fewer demands on the SSO and each web service can handle the authorization for their APIs their own way. On the other hand, having the SSO handle things means that the third parties can get access tokens that are valid across all the services, just like how users can login across all of them.

This can enable a better user experience, as otherwise the third party might have to keep asking the user for authorization as it needs to use different web services of the system, despite the separation between the different web services being invisible to the user. Of course, then either the SSO needs to have some sort of shared permission rules or each web service will still need to enforce its own rules. Also, the SSO would probably have to take some sort of text or HTML from the web services to display when asking the user to authorize the third party service.

Any suggestions? Are there any existing, publicly documented systems that do this well? Am I just over-complicating the whole thing?

Comment: Hello, sorry to say this, but I cannot see clearly your question... what are you trying to do? There is no definite answer what is proper and what is not proper - either approach can be used and it depends on your architectural point of view which is better. Can you clarify a bit more, what is your question and purpose? It would be best if you can tell a real use case that a user or a service will need to do.

Comment: Thanks Lyuben but, and I know this isn't very helpful, what parts don't you understand? I think I explain somewhat decently my systems architecture question about two ways to handle OAuth signing across a set of services using a common single sign on service. But of course, I would understand myself. ;-)